# Unable to update state in react context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my context. And i make it accessible in all the App by wrapping  . So that is not the problem. While I' m ablet o update the state in all the app i can update state by only this component.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
export const DoctorRequestContext = createContext();

export const DoctorRequestProvider = (props) => {
  const [doctorRequest, setDoctorRequest] = useState({
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    age: "",
    nationality: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    message: "",
    address: "",
    timeChecked: "",
    timeStart: "",
    timeStamp: "",
    language: [],
    modalShow: false,
    doctorChatId: "",
    doctorChatName: "",
    showChat: false,
    chatMessages: [],
    hourOfVisit: "",
    dateOfVisit: "",
    key: "home",
  });

  return (
    <DoctorRequestContext.Provider value={[doctorRequest, setDoctorRequest]}>
      {props.children}
    </DoctorRequestContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I make a copy of the current state and after i update it.   But it doesn't work

```
const handleMessageDoctor = () => {
    let newState = Object.assign({}, doctorRequest);
    newState.doctorChatId = props.doctorId;
    newState.doctorChatName = props.doctorName;
    newState.showChat = true;

    // ERRORE NON CAMBIA LO STATOOO
    console.log("new copy created", newState);
    setDoctorRequest(newState);
    console.log("after set state", doctorRequest);

    props.changeTab("chat");
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably say that the problem is the [] when you call the value.

Instead, try:

```js
value={{ doctorRequest, setDoctorRequest }}
```

**Note**: You need to use the context (useContext), restructuring the statement variable and its function

Answer (score 0):

You're passing wrong object as `value` to Context provider. Use `{}` instead of `[]`.

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
export const DoctorRequestContext = createContext();

export const DoctorRequestProvider = props => {
  const [doctorRequest, setDoctorRequest] = useState({
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    age: '',
    nationality: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    message: '',
    address: '',
    timeChecked: '',
    timeStart: '',
    timeStamp: '',
    language: [],
    modalShow: false,
    doctorChatId: '',
    doctorChatName: '',
    showChat: false,
    chatMessages: [],
    hourOfVisit: '',
    dateOfVisit: '',
    key: 'home'
  });

  const value = {
    doctorRequest,
    setDoctorRequest
  };

  return (
    <DoctorRequestContext.Provider value={value}>
      {props.children}
    </DoctorRequestContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

All will work fine, however there will be problem in checking the value with logging. Check commented line below.

```js
const { doctorRequest, setDoctorRequest } = useContext(DoctorRequestContext);

const handleMessageDoctor = () => {
  let newState = Object.assign({}, doctorRequest);
  newState.doctorChatId = props.doctorId;
  newState.doctorChatName = props.doctorName;
  newState.showChat = true;

  // ERRORE NON CAMBIA LO STATOOO
  console.log('new copy created', newState);
  setDoctorRequest(newState);
  console.log('after set state', doctorRequest); // at this point you will not see changed doctorRequest because setDoctorRequest is async function.

  props.changeTab('chat');
};
```